# System dir call to network drive prunes file path

Tags: matlab

Apologies in advance for not being able to provide a completely reproducible example, not everyone is going to have a network drive to experiment with.

I have a processing function that I'm using to perform data reduction and our data is stored on a network drive. while debugging this morning I discovered something strange (to me) and I'm curious to know why Windows (Win7, 64 bit) behaves this way. My Google-fu has been defeated.

As an example, say I have this file structure on `\\mynetworkshare`

```
\\mynetworkshare\testdata\a
\\mynetworkshare\testdata\b
\\mynetworkshare\testdata\c
\\mynetworkshare\testdata\c\day1
\\mynetworkshare\testdata\c\day2
```

With `somedatafile_n.abc` in each of the `day` folders.

My function parses through the user specified folder, `c` in this case, and looks for all of the data files that match the filter:

```
searchpath = '\\mynetworkshare\testdata\c'
oldpath = cd(searchpath); % cd to data directory for simpler dir call
[~, filenames] = system('dir /S /B somedatafile_*.abc');
filelist = regexp(filenames, '(.:\\[\w\-\\. ]+\.\w+)', 'match'); % Split filenames
cd(oldpath);
```

This returns a cell array of filenames:

```
Z:\day1\somedatafile_1.abc
Z:\day1\somedatafile_2.abc
Z:\day2\somedatafile_1.abc
```

However, these are not valid paths to use with low level I/O:

```
Error using textscan
Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.
```

It should be noted that this functions correctly if I mount the network drive and use that path instead:

```
searchpath = 'H:\testdata\c'
oldpath = cd(searchpath); % cd to data directory for simpler dir call
[~, filenames] = system('dir /S /B somedatafile_*.abc');
filelist = regexp(filenames, '(.:\\[\w\-\\. ]+\.\w+)', 'match'); % Split filenames
cd(oldpath);
```

Which returns:

```
H:\testdata\c\day1\somedatafile_1.abc
H:\testdata\c\day1\somedatafile_2.abc
H:\testdata\c\day2\somedatafile_1.abc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html

DOS does not support UNC path names. Therefore, if the current folder uses a UNC path name, then running system with a DOS command that relies on the current folder fails. To work around this limitation, change the folder to a mapped drive before calling system.

```
system('net use Z: \\mynetworkshare\testdata\c')
cd('Z:\')
fileID = fopen('day1\somedatafile_1.abc');
C = textscan(fileID,'%s %s %f32 %d8 %u %f %f %s %f');
fclose(fileID);
```

Comment: nice workaround, but it would be nice if you also show how to unmount the volume ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are only using `cd` and `dir` to get a list of file names which you can later open in Matlab, you don't *need* to use a `dos` command.

The Matlab function [`ls`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ls.html) can do that for you. *And you don't even have to change your working directory* ;-)

I've created a directory structure and files according to your example on a shared drive:

[image: folders]

Then without resorting to external command, you can get a list of the files you are interested in by:

```
baseShareName = '\\CASTOR\SharedFolder\testdata' ;

%// let's get the folder list in a variable (but you can easily hard code it if you prefer
folderList = cellstr( ls(baseShareName) ) ; %// cellstr wrapping call otherwise the output is a char array

%// return the file names of interest in the folder #5 (which is "c")
fileList = ls( [baseShareName '\' folderList{5} '\somedatafile*.abc'] )          %'// ignore this comment

%// and/or if you prefer to get the full length name (valid for later "fopen")
fullNameList = fullfile( baseShareName , folderList{5} , cellstr(fileList) )
```

Will give you:

```
fileList =
somedatafile_01.abc
somedatafile_03.abc

fullNameList = 
    '\\CASTOR\SharedFolder\testdata\c\somedatafile_01.abc'
    '\\CASTOR\SharedFolder\testdata\c\somedatafile_03.abc'
```

---

And these file names are totally ok to use with *Matlab* low level I/O functions:

```
>> fid = fopen( fullNameList{1} , 'r' )
fid =
     3
```

`3` is a valid file identifier which will work with any Matlab file operating function.

Comment: For this case I'm using the system's `dir` call because it allows for native recursion, which MATLAB's `dir` and `ls` (a wrapper for `dir`) do not support on Windows.